GitHub API Code Search Returns Only a Few Results Compared to GitHub GUI Search
My objective is to download a large number of open-source files that define Livewire components. To do this, I am trying to search for a specific string, use Livewire\Component, in all files publicly available on GitHub.
When I use the web GUI, I get almost 80k results:

https://github.com/search?type=code&q=use+Livewire%5CComponent+language%3Aphp
However, I get only 800 results when I use the API:
import requests

url = r'https://api.github.com/search/code?q=use+Livewire\Component+language:php'

headers = {
    'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28',
    'Authorization': 'Token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
}

response = requests.request('GET', url, headers=headers)
data = response.json()
print(data['total_count'])

What am I missing here? How do I retrieve all the 80k files via the API?
